# Canon MX printer series with Apple AirPrint support?

Tags: printer, ios

Does somebody know if the Canon MX printer series has a native Apple AirPrint support? In product specification they only say that it is possible to print documents from your iPhone or iPad. But i guess this means that there is a Canon app for iOS devies which can send documents to the printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Canon support. They say the MX series does not support AirPrint. You need to use a Canon App to print documents from iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Canon MX892 and I'm able to print to it wirelessly from any of my Mac equipment (Mid 2010 Macbook Pro, iPad Mini, iPhone 5).  Without any additional software or work around.